# Powershell to run 2 workflows

Tags: 2010, list, workflow, powershell

I have a Powershell that runs 2 workflows. The first workflow is on every list item and the second simply sends an email to let people know that the Powershell ran successfully.

I'm getting errors when I try to run the single workflow

**PowerShell**

```
  $web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://portal.com/sites/it" 
$manager = $web.Site.WorkFlowManager   
$list = $web.Lists["Certificate Tracking"]

$assoc = $list.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName("Certificate Notification","en-US")
$assoc.AllowAsyncManualStart = $true
$assoc.AllowManual = $true

$emails = $list.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName("Status Update","en-US")
$emails.AllowAsyncManualStart = $true
$emails.AllowManual = $true

$view = $list.Views["All Items"] #All Items
$items = $list.GetItems($view)  

$data = $assoc.AssociationData
$emData = $emails.AssociationData

$count = 0

foreach ($item in $items) {
 $wf = $manager.StartWorkFlow($item,$assoc,$data) 
}
$em = $manager.StartWorkFlow($item,$emails,$emData)

$web.Dispose()
```

**Error**

```
 Exception calling "StartWorkflow" with "3" argument(s): ""
    At C:\cert.ps1:26 char: 29
    + $em = $manager.StartWorkFlow <<<< ($item,$emails,$data)
        + CategoryInfo           : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId  :  DotNetMethodException
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error for this line `$em = $manager.StartWorkFlow($item,$emails,$emData)`

This is because scope for parameter `$item` is inside `for loop` only. And you are passing it outside `for loop` where it is undefined.

Either you can call workflow inside for loop

```
foreach ($item in $items) {
    $wf = $manager.StartWorkFlow($item,$assoc,$data) 
    $em = $manager.StartWorkFlow($item,$emails,$emData)
}
```

Or you can directly send mail using `Powershell`.

You can get some examples on google to send mail using `Powershell`.

Here is one reference: [Send mail using Powershell](http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/send-mail-using-powershell)

Comment: can i just use `$items[0]` to get one item from the list?

Comment: yes it should work..

Comment: It doesn't i get the same error

Comment: Sorry my bad, I just googled and found that we can not use index there.

Comment: Now to get single item you can either use $spListItem = $list.GetItemById(99) or write a caml query with row limit 1 this will return only single item and you can start workflow on that item.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://portal.com/sites/it" 
$manager = $web.Site.WorkFlowManager   
$list = $web.Lists["Certificate Tracking"]

$assoc = $list.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName("Certificate Notification","en-US")
$assoc.AllowAsyncManualStart = $true
$assoc.AllowManual = $true

$emails = $list.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName("Status Update","en-US")
$emails.AllowAsyncManualStart = $true
$emails.AllowManual = $true

$view = $list.Views["All Items"] #All Items
$items = $list.GetItems($view)  

$data = $assoc.AssociationData
$emData = $emails.AssociationData

$count = 0

foreach ($item in $items) {

    $wf = $manager.StartWorkFlow($item,$assoc,$data) 
    $em = $manager.StartWorkFlow($item,$emails,$emData)

}


$web.Dispose()
```

Comment: I don't want the email to kick off for every list item. Only once.

Comment: Then you need to have one more look on email list.

Comment: What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://portal.com/sites/it" 
$manager = $web.Site.WorkFlowManager   
$list = $web.Lists["Certificate Tracking"]

$assoc = $list.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName("Certificate Notification","en-US")
$assoc.AllowAsyncManualStart = $true
$assoc.AllowManual = $true

$emails = $list.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName("Status Update","en-US")
$emails.AllowAsyncManualStart = $true
$emails.AllowManual = $true

$view = $list.Views["All Items"] #All Items
$items = $list.GetItems($view)  

$data = $assoc.AssociationData
$emData = $emails.AssociationData

$errorCount = 0

Try
{
    foreach ($item in $items) {
    $wf = $manager.StartWorkFlow($item,$assoc,$data) 
    }
}
Catch [system.exception]
{
   #send email or log to file system
   $errorCount = 1
}
Finally
{
   if ($errorCount -eq 0)
   {
      $em = $manager.StartWorkFlow($item,$emails,$emData)
   }
}
```